# fastapi static files with vite build (vue3)

Tags: build, static, vuejs3, fastapi, vite

I am currently migrating from my vue2 application (created using vue cli service) to vue3 (using vite).
I have a backend written in fastapi, which serves as backend and provides the static frontend files aswell.

This is my main.py, when I use it this way, it works fine with the old application (vue cli)

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


@app.get("/{full_path:path}")
def show_test():
    return FileResponse("static/index.html", media_type="text/html")
```

My vue.config.js had this, to make it work properly:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/static/",
};
```

So the publicPath was necessary to make it work in vue2 using vue cli.

But now I created the app using vite and there is no "publicPath" anymore but a "base" attribute for the vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
...
  base: '/static/',
})
```

With this config if works, but now I am getting "static" in the url for each path, like localhost:8000/static/login and when I refresh the page it causes an error, because it does not recognize the url.

With the vue2 application and the publicPath it worked fine and only showed localhost:8000/login, and refreshes worked fine aswell.

So what need to be changed in the fastapi api.py or in the vite.config.ts to make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get it to work using a npm plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-dynamic-base

so this is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { dynamicBase } from 'vite-plugin-dynamic-base'

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    dynamicBase({
      // dynamic public path var string, default window.__dynamic_base__
      publicPath: '',
      // dynamic load resources on index.html, default false. maybe change default true
      transformIndexHtml: false
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  base: '/static/',
})
```

Now everything works.